# Input text needs to change color

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, colors

I am trying to get the text to change to light gray when I click off of it and display "password", but when I click into it I need it to change to the font color black and to the input type of "password"

***HTML :***

```
<div> 
    <input type="text" name="password" value="Password" onfocus="emptyBox(this)" onblur="fullBox(this)" style="color:#bdbdbd">
</div>
```

***JavaScript :***

```
  function emptyBox(box) {
    if (box.value == "Password") {
      box.value = "";
      box.type = "password";
      box.style = "color:#000000";
    }
  };

  function fullBox(full) {
    if (full.value == "") {
      full.value = "Password";
      full.type = "text";
      full.style = "color:#bdbdbd";
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding CSS properties in a wrong way. As one mistake occurs multiple times I am providing one example :

```
full.style.color = "#bdbdbd"
```